# Stackexchange.Redis timeout exception in .net-core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, stackexchange.redis

I'm porting a net 4 library to net-core 1.0.0-preview 2

It is using Stackexchange.Redis version 1.2.1 when developing my net-core library, and 1.2.0 for the net 4 version.

In net 4, my library has never failed when calling Redis commands.

In net-core, I get this error randomly:

```
 System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing GET netkey, inst: 6, queue: 10, qu: 0, qs: 10, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 645, ar: 0, clientName: XXXXXX, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/XXXXXXX, keyHashSlot: XXXXX(Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/Docs/Timeouts.md)
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.StringGet(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags)
```

*UPDATE* I'm using default configurations (connection timeout, connection retry, etc)

*UPDATE* Added keep-alive configuration but still failing

Any ideas?

Comment: does it work on a retry?

Comment: @BrokenGlass yes, the default value of "3" (times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: Updated SyncTimeout configuration to 10000. Tried with 5000 and failed, then with 10000 and fixed. Default value was 1000.

Comment: can you please let me where to put this configuration?

Comment: This should be part of your connection string to Redis, like "redis.cache.windows.net,password=y+v1,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,synctimeout=10000"

Answer (score 5):

Updated SyncTimeout is not a good option because your redis command is runing very slow 
The reason of timeout is .net-core default threads count in threadpool is too low.

Just set maxThreads in environment variable.

ex:

ComPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMaxWorkerThreads 1000
ComPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMinWorkerThreads 50

Then run app in administrator identity(allow app read system environment variable)

It works to me

Comment: I just added to docker ComPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMinWorkerThreads 100 and looks like it works. However, could you describe why this is so important? I am using a synchronous version of Add/Get etc from redis - but in an asynchronous method..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried upping the available threads? (Note, this is not from a .Net Core Project, so I'm not 100% certain the syntax is the same.)

I have the below in my `Application_Start` method in Global.asax.cs

```
private static int THREAD_MIN = 50; // 4 cores in production = 200
...                
//Per Redis docs, upping the number of threads available to handle the IO demands on the cloud.   
//https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Timeouts.md 
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(THREAD_MIN, THREAD_MIN);
```

Comment: Sorry, it did not help. I cannot use this method in net core. Tried another solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis (2.1.2) in my ASP MVC .NET Core 2.1 project and had also same TimeoutException on calling the synchronous method `GetString(key)` from the service `IDistributedCache`. The solution is calling rather the asynchronous method:

```
var val = await distributedCache.GetStringAsync(key)
```

the issue is no longer occurring.

Comment: It still occurs here using await async